# Not working bootstrap navbar with <ul class="nav nav-sidebar"> in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5

in my laravel application I have sidebar menu like following,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'welcome', 0,7)}}">
      <a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Home</a></li>

      <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'page1', 0,5)}}">
      <a href="{{route('page1')}}">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

this is working with Helper.php file in app/Helper/Helper.php3

```
<?php

if(! function_exists('active_menu')) {
    function active_menu($currentRouteName, $requestName, $start, $finish){
        if (substr($currentRouteName,$start, $finish) == $requestName){
            return 'active';

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

this is working fine, but now I need change above sidemenu bar  class as following,

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
```

only this change but now it is not working. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? The class nav-sidebar doesn't exist in bootstrap

Comment: Then what is the class for sidebar in bootstrap?

Comment: Well there isn't one, if you look at the following example from bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/, they made a custom sidebar in dashboard.css

Comment: No any idea here?

Comment: I think what @Tom is saying is that you can't just swap out the class `navbar-nav` for `nav-sidebar` as `nav-sidebar` is not a native bootstrap class.  Unless you have created it yourself in your css / less / sass etc?